# Is it possible to assert a query on scylla to match the content of a entity when there are Optional elements?

Tags: java, junit, assertion, optional-parameters

Suppose you have this entity:

```
public class Object {
@Nullable byte[] prop1;

byte[] prop2;

public Optional<byte[]> getProp1(){
    return Optional.ofNullable(prop1);
}
```

While doing my test for integration with Scylla I'm generating a fixture for the object and storing on Scylla. To assert that the fixture was properly stored I'm getting it back using my repository function to assert that the data was stored. As described below.

```
assertThat(result).isPresent();
assertThat(result).contains(expectedObject);
```

When no optional properties are present on the object entity, `contains` function works properly and assert that indeed we stored the data. However when involves `Optional` properties the `contains` function is unable to assert due the object hash difference.

```
obejctStored -> Object@5dtsad
obejctRetrived -> Object@53kjlas
```

My question is: is there a function for assertion that reads the content and assert the values, including Optional properties, similar what I did above?

[EDIT] - And avoid asserting value by value explicitly?

Comment: Not sure if I correctly understand your question, but maybe [`hasValue`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractOptionalAssert.html#hasValue(VALUE)) is what you are looking for

Comment: Not sure it solves the problem. Because when I didn't had the Optional value I could just use `contains` to assert all the properties in one line. Using the Optional value I'm getting this difference on the object hash. Using `hasValue` the issue persists, I have to assert property by property. But thanks :D